# Bitcoin on a cloud-based hardware security module (HSM) by AWS

Tags: hardware-wallet

As far as I know AWS does not support the secp256k1 on their cloud-based hardware security module (HSM) called CloudHSM.

[Gemini](https://gemini.com/security/) is using CloudHSM for their hot wallet.

How is it possible to implement such a solution?
Can such a solution be as safe as if the CloudHSM was supporting the secp256k1?

Comment: Where does it say they are using CloudHSM?

Comment: From the link that I provided you can find it at the hot wallet section.

Comment: Interesting, I don't see how that could be possible then.

Comment: did anybody find any explanation?

Comment: It is now https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudhsm/latest/userguide/pkcs11-key-types.html